# total hours column return two output instead of one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The below query is working perfect but it return two rows of hours which I don't want

```
SELECT
    USERINFO.name, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, 
    departments.deptname, APPROVEDHRS.hours,
    sum(workingdays) as workingdays,TotalWorkingDays
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') + 1) -
          DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') * 2 - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-01') = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
          (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-30') = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays, 
         COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d, 0, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME))) AS workingdays,
         USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, USERINFO.NAME, hours
     FROM  
         USERINFO 
     LEFT JOIN 
         CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
     LEFT JOIN 
         departments ON departments.deptid = userinfo.DEFAULTDEPTID
     LEFT JOIN 
         APPROVEDHRS ON APPROVEDHRS.userid = userinfo.userid
     WHERE
         (DEPARTMENTS.DEPTNAME = 'xyz') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME >= '2014-06-01') 
         AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME <= '2014-06-30') 
     GROUP BY 
         hours, USERINFO.BADGENUMBER, deptname, USERINFO.NAME,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 103)) blue
GROUP BY 
    name, BADGENUMBER, workingdays, TotalWorkingDays, deptname, hours
```

The output of above query :

```
name    BADGENUMBER     deptname        hours   
---------------------------------------------------
abc     1111             xyz            00:07:59    
abc     1111             xyz            00:08:00    
pqr     2222             qwe            NULL
```

Now the total hours (`APPROVEDHRS` table) in table is :

```
BADGENUMBER     NAME    DATE        HOURS
-------------------------------------------------
1111            xyz  2014-06-15     00:07:59
1111            xyz  2014-06-14     00:08:00
1111            xyz  2014-07-20     00:10:00
```

I am fetching record from 2014-06-01 to 2014-06-30

So I want the below output:

```
name       BADGENUMBER      deptname        hours   
--------------------------------------------------------       
    abc     1111             xyz            00:15:59    

    pqr     2222            qwe             NULL
```

Help me to get this desired output.

Thank you

Comment: Please you SQLFiddle to include the data for your problem.  It seems to be a rounding or time calculation issue but without the data would be difficult to help.

Comment: i have edit the query and remove all unnecessary lines.. Please try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you might want to use table names in your query so you can see where data is coming from, e.g.

```
select name,BADGENUMBER,deptname,hours,
```

...would be easier to read as:

```
select ??.name,??.BADGENUMBER,??.deptname,APPROVEDHRS.hours,
```

...or you could use aliases in the "FROM" part of your query to make this even easier to follow?

Anyway, the basic problem appears to be that you are filtering the CHECKINOUT table by date but you aren't filtering the APPROVEDHRS table.  To fix this you could change your JOIN from this:

```
left join APPROVEDHRS on APPROVEDHRS.userid = userinfo.userid
```

to this:

```
left join APPROVEDHRS on APPROVEDHRS.userid = userinfo.userid
AND (APPROVEDHRS.DATE >='2014-06-01') AND (APPROVEDHRS.DATE <='2014-06-30')
```

...and to answer your *new* question (which probably should have been created as a new question on StackOverflow).  It depends what the data type of your [hours] field is.  I tried to fix up your query as a starting point, but it is a little tricky without knowing what the data types are, etc.

So it looks like hours is a VARCHAR(?), seems odd, but here goes, note that I am assuming that your "hours" field will always be in the format '??:HH:MM.SSS' and that you only want to add the hours and minutes:

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') + 1 -
            DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2014-06-01', '2014-06-30') * 2 - 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-01') = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END - 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2014-06-30') = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TotalWorkingDays, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(d, 0,DATEDIFF(d, 0, c.CHECKTIME))) AS WorkingDays,
        d.deptname,
        u.BADGENUMBER, 
        u.NAME, 
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Hours], 4, 2)) AS [hours],
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Hours], 7, 2)) AS [minutes]
    FROM  
        USERINFO u
        LEFT JOIN CHECKINOUT c ON c.USERID = u.USERID 
        LEFT JOIN departments d ON d.deptid = u.DEFAULTDEPTID
        LEFT JOIN APPROVEDHRS a ON a.userid = u.USERID
    WHERE
        d.DEPTNAME = 'xyz'
        AND c.CHECKTIME >= '2014-06-01'
        AND c.CHECKTIME <= '2014-06-30'
    GROUP BY
        d.deptname,
        u.BADGENUMBER, 
        u.NAME, 
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Hours], 4, 2)),
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([Hours], 7, 2)))
SELECT
    Name, 
    BADGENUMBER, 
    deptname, 
    '00:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), SUM([hours]) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), SUM([minutes]) + '.000' AS [Hours],
    SUM(WorkingDays) AS WorkingDays,
    TotalWorkingDays
FROM
    Data
GROUP BY 
    Name, 
    BADGENUMBER, 
    deptname,
    TotalWorkingDays;
```

...and if that works I will be amazed :P

Answer (score 0):

If you are left-joining the ApprovedHrs table, then you'd need to limit (with a Where clause or a join clause) the dates from which those approved hours from July came from.

To clarify this, I would fully qualify the hours field with ApprovedHrs.Hours, so that it's more clear where this comes from (I'm only assuming "hours" comes from ApprovedHrs--correct me if I'm wrong).

You're just left joining on userid so it looks like ApprovedHrs will bring in everything for that user from ApprovedHrs.--Jim

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because of `GROUP BY hours` when the `hours` value is different it will create a new row for that record